# How do I refer to refer to a table to set field values via string with VBA in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to VBA and Access, but I do have some understanding.

I can set a field easily by using

```
[Field1] = Now()
```

What I want to do is save the name of a field into a string and use that variable to reference the field. This way I can save different field names into the variable and have the code act on which field name happens to be stored.

From what I can find, the proper way to do this is in my situation is:

```
Private Sub ctlUpdateButton_Click()
Dim varField as String
    varField = Dlookup("[Targeted Field]", "[Other Table]")

Cases.Fields(varField) = Now()
End Sub
```

This code breaks on the reference to Cases.Fields(varField) and reports the error as 'Run-time error '424' Object Required.

The record source for the form is a query based on the Cases table.

I'm not familiar enough with what I'm working with to know if this is a sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with `varField = Dlookup("[Targeted Field]", "[Other Table]")`

DLookup returns the value of a field in another table
Is there only one row in that table?
If so - then your code will work in theory - 
If not, you;ll have to specifiy the criteria to find the correct row

The last issue is that you can't use a table name directly in code (in your case "Cases")

If you want to change the underlying record in your form, you can modify it if the field name is in your query and it hasn't been renamed.

Simply use `Me(varField) = Now()`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Me(varField) did exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I'm not sure why, strictly, because I thoroughly searched and all answers pointed toward using the .Fields collection.

And, yes, I use a table with a single record and numerous fields to store various data for different types of 'active' items. It may really be poor design, but it has been part of my learning process.